# UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum stay at the top of screen in ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem with `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` in *ios 5*. When I present modally `UIPickerController` I want to be at the bottom of the screen and see my last photos but I'm staying at the top and have to scroll down. Same code runs perfectly in *ios 4*. Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar and I don't think you can do this (unless your roll your own custom photo picker).  So, I settled on using `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` which gets me close to this.  You get presented a choice of albums to go into and when you select Camera Roll, this shows you the photos scrolled all the way down to the bottom...to the latest photos taken.

Also, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087405/when-should-i-use-uiimagepickercontrollersourcetypephotolibrary-instead-of-uiima) helped shed some light on the differences between `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` and `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`