# When should I use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary instead of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an application that allows the user to pick a photo from their device.  To do this, I'm using the UIImagePickerController, but the problem is that I'm unsure whether I should be using a source type of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`.

On my iPhone 4 running iOS 5 the saved photos album gives a much better experience, but when I try to use my iPod Touch running iOS 4.3 using a photo that I synced from iTunes, it doesn't even show up.  If I switch to `PhotoLibrary` my iPod works but my iPhone experience is worse.  When I ask the `UIImagePickerController` it says the `SavedPhotosAlbum` is available on my iPod, but I don't seem to have a way to determine that it's empty.

What is the best way to determine which source type to use?  If I have a way to determine if the Saved Photo Album is empty, I guess that would work, but I don't see one.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` references the entire photo library, letting the user choose which album.  `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` goes straight to the camera roll album without giving the user a choice as to which album to choose from. They're similar, but different.  You can get to the camera roll from `PhotoLibrary`; you can access *only* the camera roll from `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`.

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary).

Comment: I guess what that means to me is that I'll use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum when the device has a camera, and UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary otherwise.

Comment: I'm also not sure if user's screenshots or saved images from the web will also save in the user's camera roll.

Comment: True, but for what I'm using it for, this is the right choice.