# What's the difference between Camera Roll and Photo Library?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

UIImagePickerController has these source type constants:

```
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary

UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
```

The documentation says one is for the photo library while the other is for the camera roll.

What's the exact difference between these two? Doesn't "Photo Library" contain pictures taken with the camera as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary instead of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087405/when-should-i-use-uiimagepickercontrollersourcetypephotolibrary-instead-of-uiima)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From [When should I use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary instead of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087405/when-should-i-use-uiimagepickercontrollersourcetypephotolibrary-instead-of-uiima):

`UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` references the entire photo library, letting the user choose which album.  `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` goes straight to the camera roll album without giving the user a choice as to which album to choose from. They're similar, but different.  You can get to the camera roll from `PhotoLibrary`, but you can *only* access the camera roll from `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`.

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary).

Answer (score 10):

- UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary - you can choose album for your photo library (yes, you can have more than 1 album).
- UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum - you can choose photos only in Camera Roll album.

Good luck!

Comment: I didn't even know we could have more than one album

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not the other way around.